# VS Code - Key bindings - cursor position for *type* command

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, cursor-position, keymapping, vscode-snippets

I am using VS Code Version: 1.40.0.

for quicken up my development I would need to set my own keybinding for entering a certain text ("*{|print_x}*") into the code. I managed to do that, but even better would be if the type cursor would jump right after "*{*" as soon as I'd paste the text.

So: **{** *here type curosor* **|print_x}**.

Code in *keybindings.json*:

```
 { 
    "key": "shift+alt+y", 
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": "{|print_x}", },
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
}
```

I thought using an array like that might work, but unfortunately *text* argument needs to be string.

```
   "args": { "text": [ "{" , "|print_x}" ], }
```

Is there a way to do it? If so, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this form instead:

```
 { 
    "key": "shift+alt+y",
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "{$1print_x}"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
  }
```

Because this uses the `insertSnippet` command, you can now use tabstops or variable transforms right in a keybinding without a separate snippet.  So the cursor will go to where he `$1` is.

`insertSnippet` can do what the `type` command does and gives you tabstops.

Comment: Wonderfull. Thank you a lot, that's exactly what I needed.

Where could I find more detailed information about keybindings and their setup?
There is https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings of course, it helped to understand the settings of keybindings, but there is not much detail.

Comment: Actually, I don't know of another source of info on keybindings other than that citation and SO.  Sorry.